# Simple undirected Graph question with probability

Tags: probability, graph-theory, random-graphs

Suppose that a random (simple, undirected) graph $G = (V, E)$ on a set of
$n = 10$ vertices $V = \{v_1, . . . , v_n\}$ is constructed using the following random
process: independently for each pair of vertices $v_i$, $v_j$
, $i \neq j$, with probability $1/2$ the edge $\{v_i, v_j\}$ is in the edge set $E$ (and with probability $1/2$ it is not
in $E$).

A triangle inside a graph is any set of three distinct vertices such that there
is an edge between every pair of them.

i. What is the expected number of triangles inside such a random graph
on $10$ vertices? [5 marks]

ii. Prove that the probability that this random graph contains at least $45$
different triangles is at most $1/3$. (You may quote and use any theorem
that we have proved in lectures.) [10 marks]

So I'm only on part i) but I'm a little bit stuck. So I have $P(E) = 1/2$ and $P(\bar E) = 1/2$. So then I think I'm correct in saying $P(T)$, which is the probability that there is a triangle, is $1/2*1/2*1/2 = 1/8$? From there though I'm too sure where to go. Any hints?

Comment: Whats with the instant downvote? Hardly helpful at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The probability of any particular triangle being present is $1/8$ as you say. Then by the linearity of expectation, you can get the expected number of triangles by multiplying $1/8$ by the total number of potential triangles.

This follows because we can think of the total number of triangles as the sum over possible triangles of the random variable which is $1$ if that triangle is present and $0$ otherwise. These variables are not independent, but that doesn't matter.

For the second part I suspect the result you're intended to quote is Markov's inequality.

Comment: Thanks for the help. So would the potential number of triangles be $10C3$....? This gives me 120 triangles. So expected number of triangles is 15.

Comment: I think this is wrong, hence the -1. When you have triangles that share an edge, the probability of their occurence is not independent.

Comment: Oh okay, I see. Well now I'm not too sure what to do

Comment: @bat_of_doom No, it's not wrong. The events are not independent, but they don't need to be. Google "linearity of expectation" for an explanation.

Comment: @BlackBruceLee yes, you're correct with $15$.

Comment: Nice, thanks for the help!

Comment: @EspeciallyLime What are your individual events, that you are adding? I am sorry, but this is not really clear to me.

Comment: @bat_of_doom individual events: is this triangle there? Score 1 if it is, 0 otherwise. Add these up to get the total number of triangles.

Comment: @EspeciallyLime Can you please edit your post to include this? I understand that these are really basic concepts, but its almost a year since I studied this, and downvoted because I was not convinced by your answer. I want to take back my downvote, but the site doesn't allow me to do so unless you edit your answer.

Comment: @bat_of_doom sure, no problem :)